# Is it possible for client generated jwt and server verify it?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, jjwt

I use jsonwebtoken to sign token on my client side

```
import jsonwebtoken from 'jsonwebtoken';
const { sign } = jsonwebtoken;

export const generateToken = ( ) => {
    const payload = { message: 'Hello' };
    const secret = import.meta.env.VITE_JWT_SECRET;
    console.log(secret)
    const options = { expiresIn: '5s' };
    const token = sign(payload, secret, options);
    return token;
}
```

and use it

```
export const AxiosBackend = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL_PROXY,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Token": generateToken()
    },

})
```

and this is the code to validate it

```
@Service
public class SecurityService {
    public boolean validateToken(String token,String secret) {
        try{
            byte[] secretBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret);
            Claims claims =   
 Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretBytes).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
            Date expirationDate = claims.getExpiration();
            return !expirationDate.before(new Date());

        }catch (RuntimeException exception){
            System.err.println(exception.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

but i'm always get the error

```
JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
```

i'm sure about signature match between client and server, it seem the cause is different library, but i dont know how to solve it.